# Magento 1.9.1 Var Folder

Tags: package

I see on 1.9.1 there are some new folders in the VAR folder, the one I am asking about is the PACKAGE folder. There a lot of XML files in there, can anyone shed some light on them?

thanks

Comment: not remove this file because of when u want uninstall  extension from Connect manager so easy to find auto with xml otherwise can manually remove.

Answer (score 2):

The `var/package/` folder was also there in Magento CE 1.9.0.1 and before. The `.xml` files you refer to are all packages that are installed. Those files are used by the Magento Connect Manager. They contain info like, the name, version and dependencies of the packages.

they come from the package.xml which every package on magento connect needs/has. It contains for example all files, which belong to this module and is important if you update or remove modules via the Connect Download Manager.

> **NOTE:** Packages which are installed manually (not through Magento
>   Connect Manager) are not listed in the `var/package/` folder.